# Javafx | Child nodes are NULL after loading a new FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

i've a Media Player and i'm trying to dinamically load 2 Scenes (FXML files) in the same Scene, and it works!

Both the FXML GUIs share the same Controller (*is it an error?*).

Here some explanatory pics:

[First Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RikbT.png)

[Second Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLw6I.png)

Inside the FXML Controller class, i've declared the Child nodes of both the FXML files, as follow:

```
public class MediaPlayerControllerNew implements Initializable {

private  javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, mediaPlayerL, mediaPlayerR;

@FXML
private javafx.scene.media.MediaView mediaView, mediaViewR, mediaViewL;

@FXML
private javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane mediaPaneL, mediaPaneR;

@FXML
private javafx.scene.control.SplitPane splitPane;
@FXML
private javafx.scene.layout.HBox bottomBar;

@FXML
private javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane rootPane;
```

But after i've loaded the second FXML file, the child nodes that should be loaded:

- mediaViewR
- mediaViewL
- splitPane

***are NULL***..... ***How do I fix it?***

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Both the FXML GUIs share the same Controller" is almost certainly not true. Probably what you mean is "both of the controllers are from the same class". The `FXMLLoader` creates a new controller when it loads an FXML file. "*is it an error*": it is almost always an error to use the same class for controllers for different FXML files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @James_D ! :D